# GCC disagrees with Clang and MSVC when concept that's always true is used to implement a concept

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following code fails to compile with Clang 13 and MSVC v19.29 VS16.11 but successfully compiles with GCC 11.2.

```
template <typename...>
concept always_true = true;

template <typename T>
concept refable = always_true<T&>;

static_assert(refable<void>);
```

Clang 13:

```
<source>:9:1: error: static_assert failed
static_assert(refable<void>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:15: note: because 'void' does not satisfy 'refable'
static_assert(refable<void>);
              ^
<source>:7:32: note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: cannot form a reference to 'void'
concept refable = always_true<T&>;
                               ^
```

MSVC v19.29 VS16.11 :

```
<source>(9): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GvM755oe5)

Is GCC wrong here? I expected `refable<void>` to evaluate to false since it forms an invalid type(`void&`) in the immediate context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> static_assert(refable<void>);
> ```

As per [[temp.names]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#8), `refable<void>` is a *concept-id*:

> A *concept-id* is a *simple-template-id* where the *template-name* is a *concept-name*. A *concept-id* is a prvalue of type `bool`, and does not name a template specialization. A *concept-id* evaluates to `true` **if the concept's normalized *constraint-expression*** is satisfied ([temp.constr.constr]) by the specified template arguments and `false` otherwise.

The concept's normalization is thus not dependent on the template arguments in a given *concept-id* that names the concept, but something that is performed independently; however the use of a *concept-id* may be the trigger for *performing* normalization of a concept, [[temp.constr.normal]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.normal#note-1):

> [Note 1: Normalization of constraint-expressions is performed when determining the associated constraints ([temp.constr.constr]) of a declaration and when evaluating the value of an id-expression that names a concept specialization ([expr.prim.id]). — end note]

Constraint normalization is covered by [[temp.constr.normal]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.normal#1), where particularly /1.4 is governing the OP's example:

> The normal form of an expression E is a constraint that is defined as
> follows:
>
> - [...]
> - **/1.4** The normal form of a *concept-id* `C<A1, A2, ..., An>` is **the normal form of the constraint-expression of `C`**, after substituting `A1, A2, ..., An` for `C`'s respective template
>   parameters **in the parameter mappings in each atomic constraint**. If
>   any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the
>   program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.
>
>   [Example 1:
>
>   ```
>   template<typename T> concept A = T::value || true;
>   template<typename U> concept B = A<U*>;
>   template<typename V> concept C = B<V&>;
>   ```
>
>   Normalization of `B`'s constraint-expression is valid and results in
>   `T​::​value` (with the mapping `T↦U*`) `∨ true` (with an empty
>   mapping), despite the expression `T​::​value` being ill-formed for a
>   pointer type `T`. Normalization of `C`'s constraint-expression results
>   in the program being ill-formed, because it would form the invalid
>   type `V&*` in the parameter mapping. — end example]

The key question here is whether OP's example runs into the

> substituting [...] **in the parameter mappings** in each atomic constraint. If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

or not.

The normalization of `refable`'s constraint-expression, however, results in `true` (with an empty mapping), with emphasis on the empty mapping in this normalized constraint. Thus, the normal form of OP's `refable<void>` *concept-id*, would be substituting `void` into the parameter mapping of the normalized form of `refable`, but this only contains an empty parameter mapping. Thus the program is not ill-formed, NDR under [temp.constr.normal]/1.4, and the parameter mapping will never fail as there is nothing to substitute in the single empty mapping.

The question whether

> ```
> refable<void>
> ```

results in a satisfied (`true`) constraint or not (`false`) comes down to how to interpret [[temp.constr.atomic]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.atomic#3.sentence-2):

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the parameter mapping **and template arguments are first substituted into its expression**. If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied. [...]

This one is a bit tricky to read unambiguously (particularly the emphasized part), but as the parameter mapping is empty, there can be no substitution failure regarding the parameter mapping, and I interpret the emphasized part as substitution of template arguments into the normalized constraint-expression, which contains no template parameters, meaning there is no substitution failure. This would argue for GCC actually being correct to accept the program.

Comment: May I ask why or how this is decided? Do we have to write `template<typename T> concept C = requires {typename T;};`, even if there's already a `typename T` in template parameter list ?