# Why is substitution failure in parameter mappings considered ill-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, language-design, c++-concepts

In [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/Gzvr5cvPb),

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
concept always_true = true;

template<class T>
concept always_true_if_tagged = always_true<T, typename T::tag>;

struct A {
    using tag = int;
};

static_assert(always_true_if_tagged<A>);
static_assert(!always_true_if_tagged<int>);  //GCC says this failed
```

GCC says that the second assertion failed. Both Clang and MSVC are agree to compile it.

I originally thought that it is ill-form with no diagnostic required, because of [temp.constr.normal#1.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#1.4)

> The normal form of a concept-id `C<A1, A2, ..., An>` is the normal form of the constraint-expression of `C`, after substituting `A1, A2, ..., An` for `C`'s respective template parameters in the parameter mappings in each atomic constraint. **If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.**

The substitution `T::typename tag` is a parameter mapping for `always_true`, so it is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

So my first two questions are

1. **Was I correct?** (Is it ill-formed and did I cite the correct reason?)
2. **Why it should be ill-formed?** (If I was correct.)

---

One of the solutions is to check the nested typename before. So the parameter mapping for `always_true` doesn't happen.

```cpp
template<class T>
concept always_true_if_tagged =
    requires {typename T::tag;}
    && always_true<T, typename T::tag>;
```

Furthermore, [temp.constr.atomic#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3) says

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression. **If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied.** Otherwise, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed if necessary, and `E` shall be a constant expression of type `bool`. The constraint is satisfied if and only if evaluation of `E` results in `true`. If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

If I write

```cpp
template<class T>
concept always_true_if_tagged = bool(always_true<T, typename T::tag>);
```

`bool(always_true<T, typename T::tag>)` is an atomic constraint IIUC. The substitution of `T::typename tag` with `T=int` results in invalid type, so it should be well-formed and not satisfied.

So my last two(or four) questions are

3. **Why this doesn't apply to the first code or why [temp.constr.normal#1.4] doesn't apply here?**

- 3.1. Is this substitution a parameter mapping for concept-id `always_true`?
- 3.2. Is the usage of `always_true` in `concept C = always_true<T, typename T::tag>` an atomic contraint? [temp.constr.constr#general-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#general-1) says there are three different kinds of constraints: conjunctions, disjunctions and atomic constraints.

4. **Why can't `concept C = always_true<T, typename T::tag>` with `T=int` be well-formed like this one?** (Likely the same as the second question though)

---

**Edit**: As I said in the comments, I've noticed [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69823200/gcc-disagrees-with-clang-and-msvc-when-concept-thats-always-true-is-used-to-imp). But this is a **"WHY"** question, not just asking what is defined in the standard, **but more importantly what is the motivation**. For example, what is reason that the standard cannot consider `always_true_if_tagged<int>` well-formed and not satisfied, as I asked in that answer's comment(and have no reply yet), we can solve this issue by just adding `requires {typename T;}` but `typename T` is already in parameter list which makes the solution seem redundant.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69823200 (TLDR: `always_true_if_tagged<T>` is normalised to the atomic constraint `true` with an empty parameter mapping. So `always_true_if_tagged<T>` is always `true` for any `T`, whether it has a `tag` or not, so `static_assert(always_true_if_tagged<int>);` should succeed.)

Comment: @Artyer Oh that seems make sense. Didn't find that question before, thanks. Although it doesn't answer this question as ask in title and raise me another question why *should* unmapped parameters be ignored...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC disagrees with Clang and MSVC when concept that's always true is used to implement a concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69823200/gcc-disagrees-with-clang-and-msvc-when-concept-thats-always-true-is-used-to-imp)

Comment: @Quuxplusone This is a WHY question, not only what's defined in the standard, but also what's the intention.

Comment: Your prior check with `requires` doesn't actually help you, since your first quote still applies. It requires substituting in _each_ atomic constraint.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the lhs of scope resolution operator (::) can only be ["a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup#:%7E:text=If%20the%20name%20found%20on%20the%20left%20does%20not%20designate%20a%20namespace%20or%20a%20class%2C%20enumeration%2C%20or%20dependent%20type%2C%20the%20program%20is%20ill%2Dformed), ill-formed otherwise.

With my experiment, `always_true_if_tagged<int>` is actually evaluate to `true` in gcc compiler, so the `static_assert` failed is because of evaluating to false. I guess that gcc compiler assumed that regardless of `T, U`, `always_true` is always `true`, so optimized out the evaluation of `typename T::tag` in constraint normalization.

So my answers to your questions:

1. I believe that you are correct.
2. The compiler has no idea whether the constraint is satisfied in this state (constraint normalization), and cannot perform further evaluation until a concept returns true or false.
3. As descibe above, I think compiler optimzed out the evaluation.

   1. Subtitution is happend when concept is used, and parameter mapping is "created" when concept is declared, see follow.
   2. [Atomic constraint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#:%7E:text=struct%20equal_to%3B-,Atomic%20constraints,AND%20or%20logical%20OR%20expression%20(those%20form%20conjunctions%20and%20disjunctions%2C%20respectively).,-Satisfaction%20of%20an)

   > An atomic constraint consists of an expression E and a mapping from the template parameters that appear within E to template arguments involving the template parameters of the constrained entity, called its parameter mapping.
4. I believe you have the answer now.

Answer (score -4):

1. Were you correct? […]
   Yes `typename T::tag` doesn’t name a valid type with `[T = int]`.
2. Why should it be ill-formed?
   The reason you cited is right. `typename int::tag` is just non-sense.
   From memory, you’d also need to move the template specialization below the `struct A` to use `typename A::tag` in the [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates/).
3. Why […]
   I don’t *believe* this is well-formed because of [§7.3.2 [conv.lval]](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#1)
   I don’t have the answer to the questions, only more questions.

In a concept, it’s not a template instantiation (See: [[temp.concept]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#5), [[temp.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#general-5), [[temp.dep]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#type)), so I don’t understand how that could be an atomic constraint (is it a constant expression? How can it evaluate to anything).

[clang 14.0.0 doesn’t generate warnings with `-fsanitize=undefined` on](https://godbolt.org/z/38vGs6jeo)

See also:
[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: *typename int::tag is just non-sense.*  This doesn't answer *why it SHOULD be ill-formed*. Non-sense doesn't means that it have to be ill-formed. It might be well-formed but not satifisfied, like requirements in requires expression or subsitution in atomic constraints.

Comment: *From memory, you’d also need to move the template specialization below the struct A to use typename A::tag in the template.*  Sorry, I dont see how this is releated to this question.

Comment: *I don’t believe this is well-formed because of §7.3.2 [conv.lval].*   I think my cited [temp.constr.atomic#3] in OP says that *the parameter mapping and template arguments are **first** substituted into its expression. If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint **is not satisfied**. **Otherwise**, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed if necessary [...]*

Comment: > This doesn't answer why it SHOULD be ill-formed.  
It does, though. You cited a reason why it has to be invalid. The expression `typename T::X` means specifically that `T::X` names a type (in this context). `int::tag` isn’t valid anything, much less a type. (Again this is all from memory, it’s 2am so unfortunately, I don’t have time to cite anything. It should be in [temp.dep] cited above or [basic.lookup]; unsure)